# How can this haskell rolling sum implementation be improved?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

How can I improve the the following rolling sum implementation?

```
type Buffer  = State BufferState (Maybe Double)
type BufferState = ( [Double] , Int, Int )

-- circular buffer    
buff :: Double -> Buffer 
buff newVal = do
  ( list, ptr, len) <- get
  -- if the list is not full yet just accumulate the new value
  if length list < len
    then do
      put ( newVal : list , ptr, len)
      return Nothing
    else do
      let nptr = (ptr - 1) `mod` len
          (as,(v:bs)) = splitAt ptr list
          nlist = as ++ (newVal : bs)
      put (nlist, nptr, len)
      return $ Just v

-- create intial state for circular buffer
initBuff l = ( [] , l-1 , l)

-- use the circular buffer to calculate a rolling sum
rollSum :: Double -> State (Double,BufferState) (Maybe Double)
rollSum newVal = do
  (acc,bState) <- get
  let (lv , bState' )  = runState (buff newVal) bState
      acc' = acc + newVal
  -- subtract the old value if the circular buffer is full
  case lv of
    Just x  -> put ( acc' - x , bState') >> (return $ Just (acc' - x))
    Nothing -> put ( acc' , bState')     >> return Nothing

test :: (Double,BufferState) -> [Double] -> [Maybe Double] -> [Maybe Double]
test state [] acc = acc
test state (x:xs) acc = 
  let (a,s) = runState (rollSum x) state
  in test s xs (a:acc)

main :: IO()
main = print $ test (0,initBuff 3) [1,1,1,2,2,0] []
```

Buffer uses the State monad to implement a circular buffer. rollSum uses the State monad again to keep track of the rolling sum value and the state of the circular buffer.

- How could I make this more elegant?
- I'd like to implement other functions like rolling average or a difference, what could I do to make this easy?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention I am using a circular buffer as I intend to use this code on-line and process updates as they arrive - hence the need to record state. Something like

```
newRollingSum = update rollingSum newValue
```

Comment: I didn't read the source, but I did run `main` after replacing your test list with one that should reveal behavior pretty clearly, namely, `[1,10,100,1000,10000,100000]`. The result shows it adds three elements starting at indices 3, then 2, then 1; but never starting at index 0. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't managed to decipher all of your code, but here is the plan I would take for solving this problem. First, an English description of the plan:

1. We need windows into the list of length `n` starting at each index.

   1. Make windows of arbitrary length.
   2. Truncate long windows to length `n`.
   3. Drop the last `n-1` of these, which will be too short.
2. For each window, add up the entries.

This was the first idea I had; for windows of length three it's an okay approach because step `2` is cheap on such a short list. For longer windows, you may want an alternate approach, which I will discuss below; but this approach has the benefit that it generalizes smoothly to functions other than `sum`. The code might look like this:

```
import Data.List

rollingSums n xs
    = map sum                              -- add up the entries
    . zipWith (flip const) (drop (n-1) xs) -- drop the last n-1
    . map (take n)                         -- truncate long windows
    . tails                                -- make arbitrarily long windows
    $ xs
```

If you're familiar with the "equational reasoning" approach to optimization, you might spot a first place we can improve the performance of this function: by swapping the first `map` and `zipWith`, we can produce a function with the same behavior but with a `map f . map g` subterm, which can be replaced by `map (f . g)` to get slightly less allocation.

Unfortunately, for large `n`, this adds `n` numbers together in the inner loop; we would prefer to simply add the value at the "front" of the window and subtract the one at the "back". So we need to get trickier. Here's a new idea: we'll traverse the list twice in parallel, `n` positions apart. Then we'll use a simple function for getting the rolling sum (of unbounded window length) of prefixes of a list, namely, `scanl (+)`, to convert this traversal into the actual sums we're interested in.

```
rollingSumsEfficient n xs = scanl (+) firstSum deltas where
    firstSum = sum (take n xs)
    deltas   = zipWith (-) (drop n xs) xs -- front - back
```

There's one twist, which is that `scanl` never returns an empty list. So if it's important that you be able to handle short lists, you'll want another equation that checks for these. Don't use `length`, as that forces the entire input list into memory before starting the computation -- a potentially lethal performance mistake. Instead add a line like this above the previous definition:

```
rollingSumsEfficient n xs | null (drop (n-1) xs) = []
```

We can try these two out in ghci. You'll notice that they do not *quite* have the same behavior as yours:

```
*Main> rollingSums 3 [10^n | n <- [0..5]]
[111,1110,11100,111000]
*Main> rollingSumsEfficient 3 [10^n | n <- [0..5]]
[111,1110,11100,111000]
```

On the other hand, the implementations are considerably more concise and are fully lazy in the sense that they work on infinite lists:

```
*Main> take 5 . rollingSums 10 $ [1..]
[55,65,75,85,95]
*Main> take 5 . rollingSumsEfficient 10 $ [1..]
[55,65,75,85,95]
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I like rollingSumsEfficient! - I've added a little extra detail to the question and will leave it open a little longer.

Comment: @DaveAnderson The comment about laziness *is* a comment about processing things online, isn't it? All the state is there, just hidden behind a pure interface. For example, try `main = interact (unlines . map show . rollingSums 3 . map read . lines)` and type a few lines of input. You'll see the output go scrolling by as it becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient implementation for rolling sum in haskell-

```hs
rollingSums :: Num a => Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
rollingSums n xs | n <= 0    = Nothing
                 | otherwise = Just $ if length as == n then go (sum as) xs bs else []
  where
    (as, bs) = splitAt n xs
    
    go s xs []     = [s]
    go s xs (y:ys) = s : go (s + y - head xs) (tail xs) ys
```

Asuming that - sum((i+1)...(i+1+n)) = sum(i..(i+n)) - arr[i] + arr[i+n+1]